# Uploading Revit files to Model Derivative API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I use Model derivative API and it work fine for IFC, FBX, and OBJ. But, when I upload Revit files, I get errors.The error is: "The file is not a Revit file or is not a supported version." I have tried a dozen of Revit files from different sources and vesions. I always get this error. I guess the models are fine as viewer.autodesk.com can open them. Could you please advise how I can address this issue? Below is the error message I get:

```
{
  "type": "manifest",
  "hasThumbnail": "false",
  "status": "failed",
  "progress": "complete",
  "region": "US",
  "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZmFjaWxpdHlfNDMvZGJkZTgyYzItNjNiZi00N2NhLTlkZDgtMmM2OGYwYTQ1MGJmLnJ2dA",
  "version": "1.0",
  "derivatives": [
    {
      "name": "dbde82c2-63bf-47ca-9dd8-2c68f0a450bf.rvt",
      "hasThumbnail": "false",
      "status": "failed",
      "progress": "complete",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": "error",
          "code": "Revit-UnsupportedFileType",
          "message": "<message>The file is not a Revit file or is not a supported version.</message>"
        },
        {
          "type": "error",
          "message": "Possibly recoverable warning exit code from extractor: -536870935",
          "code": "TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
        }
      ],
      "outputType": "svf"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the Revit Version of the RVT file you uploaded to Forge service? Currently, MD API only supports RVT file generated from Revit 2016 and later.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eason. (2-3) 2020, (2) 2019, (1) 2017, and a couple older than 2016. I got the same error for all.

Comment: Could you share your POST jobs request JSON body? There might be something wrong in the body.

Comment: @EasonKang Below are all the three JSON bodies I receive from Forge:

Comment: Upload Response oss/v2/buckets/
{
  "bucketKey": "facility_43",
  "objectId": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:facility_43/864cd131-85d4-4acc-afa7-084714b219be.rvt",
  "objectKey": "864cd131-85d4-4acc-afa7-084714b219be.rvt",
  "sha1": "beb1c7ea46f0498a072ec5fde6b0dd35c65f4021",
  "size": 11925233,
  "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
  "location": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/facility_43/objects/864cd131-85d4-4acc-afa7-084714b219be.rvt"
}

Comment: Convert response modelderivative/v2/designdata/job
{
  "result": "success",
  "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZmFjaWxpdHlfNDMvODY0Y2QxMzEtODVkNC00YWNjLWFmYTctMDg0NzE0YjIxOWJlLnJ2dA",
  "acceptedJobs": {
    "output": {
      "destination": {
        "region": "us"
      },
      "formats": [
        {
          "type": "svf",
          "views": [
            "3d"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: (JSON BODY 3 - PART1)
Check Status   modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/manifest
{
  "type": "manifest",
  "hasThumbnail": "false",
  "status": "failed",
  "progress": "complete",
  "region": "US",
  "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZmFjaWxpdHlfNDMvODY0Y2QxMzEtODVkNC00YWNjLWFmYTctMDg0NzE0YjIxOWJlLnJ2dA",
  "version": "1.0",
  "derivatives": [
    {
      "name": "864cd131-85d4-4acc-afa7-084714b219be.rvt",
      "hasThumbnail": "false",
      "status": "failed",
      "progress": "complete",

Comment: (JSON BODY 3 - PART2)
"messages": [
        {
          "type": "error",
          "code": "Revit-UnsupportedFileType",
          "message": "<message>The file is not a Revit file or is not a supported version.</message>"
        },
        {
          "type": "error",
          "message": "Possibly recoverable warning exit code from extractor: -536870935",
          "code": "TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
        }
      ],
      "outputType": "svf"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Please note that we use .NET CORE for development of our solution.

Comment: Many thanks for those information. I have passed it to our engineering team, will get back ASAP.

Comment: Meanwhile, may I ask a favor to check if the upload file size of the failed RVT is the same as it in your hard disk?

Comment: @EasonKang Thank you! The size of the Revit file I uploaded is 6420KB. In the first JASON file the value of "size" attribute is: "11925233"